# Tomcat not starting after changing packaging from jar to war

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat

Firstly, after changing the packaging from jar to war for spring boot application, I am not able to do maven build. Getting below error:

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.goel.GameApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)*

The above error comes when maven tries to run app tests. So I commented out the test and ran maven build and I was able to get a war file.
But after deploying the same war file in tomcat(aws), I am getting the same error.

I have followed the 3 step approach properly.Ref: https://www.javadream.in/convert-jar-to-war-in-spring-boot/

I have checked that the build-path does not exclude resource or application.properties

I have tried moving from spring IDE to Eclipse IDE.

I have opened the war file and have verified that the application.properties file is present under WEB-INF/classes/application.properties.

I have read and tried many other things but nothing helped. Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks in advance.
Please do let me know if more info is required,

Java Version: 1.8 ,
Maven Version: 3.6.3 ,
spring-boot-starter-parent: **2.5.4**

[Exploded war file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNxE0.png)

[Screenshot for SSGApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Hm4.png)

Comment: This has nothing to do with AWS as you can reproduce it off AWS too so I will remove the tags if that's OK with you?

Comment: Seems like an incorrect `@PropertySource`: the path `/application.properties` means different things in different `ApplicationContext`s. What version of Spring Boot are you using? Can you add your `GameApplication` class to your question (edit the question)?

Comment: Make sure that application.properties is at the root of the WAR file.  The main class is different: has to extend SpringBootServletInitializer.  Could be a problem with your Maven packaging.  https://vaadin.com/blog/packaging-and-deploying-spring-boot-applications-as-war-files

Comment: The asked information has been added in the question itself by editing it.

Comment: Please don't post code as images, but as text (cf. [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11748454)). The error message does not concern `SSGApplication` you added, but another config class: `GameApplication`. My guess is: it is annotated with `@PropertySource("/application.properties")` instead of `@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")`.

Comment: I have changed the name of the class from GameApplication to SSGApplication.